# Update data sent by php form using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I can't really figure out this problem , let's say that on the page there is a form with one input in it , if you submit the form then the text that you save will be sent to the database and stored now , i would like to get user location:

Longitude
Latitude

whenever he submits the form , now I found that it's better to get the location using Javascript and then send it to the server using AJAX so basically when i submit the form the text of input is stored in the database and , I marked the submit button with id "submit" and I want to use ajax with jquery so:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url:'update_the_last_form_submit_data.php', 
    type:'POST', 
    data:{lat:lat,lat:lat}
    success:, 
    error: 
});
```

so what i want to do is , when ever the user submits the form , ajax will add the current longitude and latitude to the MySQL query which is being sent to database

and  finally the table will look like this :

**Time------------User Input--------Latitude---------Longitude**
xx-xx-xx--------What you tiped----Detected longitude-------detected latitude

edit:

I don't know how do i do it

basically i have a click function with the ajax code but I don't know when i send the ajax request how do i know which row is the one that was just sent by me to php

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
   $.ajax({ 
        url:'update_the_last_form_submit_data.php', 
        type:'POST', 
        data:{lat:lat,lat:lat}
        success:, 
        error: 
    });


});
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: It's unclear what the question is.

Comment: i dont know how do  i update the record that was just sent to db by php

Comment: @wolf4 pls post ur html as well.

Comment: ^^... and php code

Comment: its not about php code now , after the form is submited , i receive the variables using post method and then what i need to do is i need to update the row that was sent by php , i need to update the coordinations , but how do i know that this is the row that was just send by me ? because there can be like  10 requests per sec and i cant just select the last one in the database , i will use UPDATE query but update where ? and where how do i know that here it goes i need some kind of id there ?

Comment: in php after the update put the same data in the response. then in javacsript at the client update

Comment: You need to put some kind of ownership into your table like the `id` of the user that is doing all this. Then add that to your web page, and pass it back with the Lat and Long so you know which row in the database to update

Comment: You might also want to add a `Event.preventDefault()` into your AJAX flow to stop everything being done twice

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i probably came with the solution , when user submits the form , i will save the session user name in the database and when the ajax code will be triggered it will update the last record which was made by the session of the current user